# Right syntax for redirecting script

Tags: php, redirect

I have a "Show me other car" button on my website that lead to redirect.php and I want to send some data to that file using GET to redirect user to right website. This script redirect to other car from same category and same model.

Link looks like this: redirect.php?make=someting&model=something

For example: redirect.php?make=bmw&model=x5

Now I have some php data in redirect.php:

```
 $model = $_GET['model'];
 $make = $_GET['make'];
 $bmw = "http://website.com/bmw/model.php?=$model"
 $mercedes = "http://website.com/mercedes/model.php?=$model"
 $audi = "http://website.com/audi/model.php?=$model"
```

and so on.

Right now I'm using script that isn't truly random, it looks like this:

```
<?php       
function urlredirect()
{
$value=0;
$url =array(
'http://www.website.com/bmw/x5/01/',
'http://www.website.com/bmw/x5/02/',
'http://www.website.com/special/',
'http://www.website.com/bmw/x5/03/',
); 
$urlc = count($url)-1;
if ($_COOKIE["next_car_redirect"]=='') 
{
setcookie("next_car_redirect", $value,time()+86400);
header ("Location: $url[$value]"); 
}
if ($_COOKIE["next_car_redirect"]!='') 
{
$getcookie=htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["next_car_redirect"]);
if($urlc >$getcookie)
{
$getcookie=$getcookie+1;
}
setcookie("next_car_redirect", $getcookie,time()+86400);
header ("Location: $url[$getcookie]");
}
}
urlredirect(); 
?>
```

This script allow me to redirect user to the next url every time he click and to show him special car after 3th click. But it is really hard to create script like this for every car model...

Now for example I have a link "Show me randome BMW X5" (redirect.php?make=bmw&model=x5) when surfer click on that link I want redirect him to: website.com/bmw/model.php?=x5,

Now on that website surfer click "Show me randome Audi A6" (redirect.php?make=audi&model=a6) it is surfers 2nd click so I want redirect him to (in this case) website.com/audi/model.php?=a6.

Now on that website surfer click on "Show me randome BMW X3" (redirect.php?make=bmw&model=x3) it is 3th click so now I want redirect surfer to website.com/special/ (instead  website.com/bmw/model.php?=x3).

4th and every other click lead to website.com/car/model.php?=model, no more specials.

My problem is that I do not know how to create right syntax.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
$model = $_GET['model'];
$make = $_GET['make'];
$bmw = "http://website.com/bmw/model.php?=".$model;
$mercedes = "http://website.com/mercedes/model.php?=".$model;
$audi = "http://website.com/audi/model.php?=".$model;
$link = "$" .$make;

function urlredirect()
{
$value=0;
$url =array(
'$link',
'$link',
'http://www.website.com/special/',
'$link',
```

...

Comment: What do you mean by right syntax? Are you struggling with PHP's syntax? Are you missing information on what PHP functions you should use? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, PHP syntax. How to create from all that data from GET, link one, two and three. My biggest problem is how to set everything up in $url arrey.

Answer (score 0):

OK I did it with additional array, just putting links to array and then fetching them with $_GET

```
$model = $_GET['model'];
$make = $_GET['make'];

$link = array(
    "http://website.com/bmw/model.php?=".$model, 
    "http://website.com/mercedes/model.php?=".$model, 
    "http://website.com/audi/model.php?=".$model);


$url[0] = $link[$make];
$url[1] = $link[$make];
$url[2] = "http://www.website.com/special";
$url[3] = $link[$make];
```